# USB Device written with m-stack does not enumerate properly

Tags: c, usb, pic, descriptor

I'm using m-stack on a Pic18F25K50.  The device is supposed to be 3 devices when I plug it into my PC.  I am cloning a USB touch screen controller.  I don't see anything wrong in my descriptor, but windows says each of the 3 devices will not start. Below I attached the descriptors, the configuration code, and what usblyzer shows. I hope someone can see what I'm doing wrong. I've looked at this code a number of times and see nothing wrong.

```
struct configuration_1_packet {
struct configuration_descriptor  config;
struct interface_descriptor      interface;
struct hid_descriptor            hid;
struct endpoint_descriptor       ep;
struct interface_descriptor      interface2;
struct hid_descriptor            hid2;
struct endpoint_descriptor       ep2;
struct endpoint_descriptor       ep2_out;
struct interface_descriptor      interface3;
struct hid_descriptor            hid3;
struct endpoint_descriptor       ep3;
};


const ROMPTR struct device_descriptor this_device_descriptor =
{
sizeof(struct device_descriptor), // bLength
DESC_DEVICE, // bDescriptorType
0x0200, // 0x0200 = USB 2.0, 0x0110 = USB 1.1
0x00, // Device class
0x00, // Device Subclass
0x00, // Protocol.
EP_0_LEN, // bMaxPacketSize0
0x2965, // Vendor
0x5042, // Product 5023 is the actual kortek module we use
0x0100, // device release (1.0)
1, // Manufacturer
2, // Product
3, // Serial
1 // NumConfigurations
};

{
{
// Members from struct configuration_descriptor
sizeof(struct configuration_descriptor),
0x02,//Configuration Descriptor bDescriptorType
sizeof(configuration_1), // wTotalLength (length of the whole packet)
3, // bNumInterfaces
1, // bConfigurationValue
0, // iConfiguration (index of string descriptor)
0b10100000,//bmAttributes
100/2,   // 100/2 indicates 100mA
},

{
// Members from struct interface_descriptor
sizeof(struct interface_descriptor), // bLength;
0x04,//Descriptor Type
0x00, // InterfaceNumber
0x00, // AlternateSetting
0x01, // bNumEndpoints (num besides endpoint 0)
0x03, // bInterfaceClass 3=HID, 0xFF=VendorDefined
0x00, // bInterfaceSubclass (0=NoBootInterface for HID)
0x00, // bInterfaceProtocol
0x04, // iInterface (index of string describing interface)
},

{
// Members from struct hid_descriptor
sizeof(struct hid_descriptor),
0x21,
0x0110, // bcdHID
0x0, // bCountryCode
1,   // bNumDescriptors
0x22, // bDescriptorType2
sizeof(mouse_report_descriptor), // wDescriptorLength supposed to be 22F
},

{
// Members of the Endpoint Descriptor (EP1 IN)
sizeof(struct endpoint_descriptor),
0x05, //bDescriptorType Endpoint
0x84, // endpoint #1 0x80=IN
0b00000011, // bmAttributes
EP_1_IN_LEN, // wMaxPacketSize
1, // bInterval in ms.
},


    /* Second Interface */
{
// Members from struct interface_descriptor
sizeof(struct interface_descriptor), // bLength;
0x04, //Interface
0x01, // InterfaceNumber
0x00, // AlternateSetting
0x02, // bNumEndpoints (num besides endpoint 0)
0x03, // bInterfaceClass 3=HID, 0xFF=VendorDefined
0x00, // bInterfaceSubclass (0=NoBootInterface for HID)
0x00, // bInterfaceProtocol
0x05, // iInterface (index of string describing interface)
},

{
    // Members from struct hid_descriptor
sizeof(struct hid_descriptor),
0x21,  //bDescriptorType HID
0x0110, // bcdHID
0x00, // bCountryCode
1,   // bNumDescriptors
0x22, // bDescriptorType2
sizeof(mouse_report_descriptor_1), // wDescriptorLength supposed to be 27Bytes
},

{
// Members of the Endpoint Descriptor (EP1 OUT)
sizeof(struct endpoint_descriptor),
0x05, //bDescriptorType Endpoint
0x85 /*| 0x00*/, // endpoint #1 0x00=OUT
0b00000011, // bmAttributes
EP_1_OUT_LEN, // wMaxPacketSize
1, // bInterval in ms.
},


{
// Members of the Endpoint Descriptor (EP1 IN)
sizeof(struct endpoint_descriptor),
0x05,//bDescriptorType Endpoint
0x05, // endpoint #1 0x80=IN
0b00000011, // bmAttributes
EP_2_IN_LEN, // wMaxPacketSize
1, // bInterval in ms.
},

    /* Third Interface */
{
// Members from struct interface_descriptor
sizeof(struct interface_descriptor), // bLength;
0x04, //bDescriptorType Interface
0x02, // InterfaceNumber
0x00, // AlternateSetting
0x01, // bNumEndpoints (num besides endpoint 0)
0x03, // bInterfaceClass 3=HID, 0xFF=VendorDefined
0x00, // bInterfaceSubclass (0=NoBootInterface for HID)
0x02, // bInterfaceProtocol
0x06, // iInterface (index of string describing interface)
},


{
// Members from struct hid_descriptor
sizeof(struct hid_descriptor),
0x21, //bDescriptorType HID
0x0110, // bcdHID
0x00, // bCountryCode
0x01,   // bNumDescriptors
0x22, // bDescriptorType Report
sizeof(mouse_report_descriptor_2), // wDescriptorLength supposed to be 56bytes
},

{
// Members of the Endpoint Descriptor (EP1 OUT)
sizeof(struct endpoint_descriptor),
0x05, //bDescriptorType Endpoint
0x83, // endpoint #1 0x00=OUT
0b00000011, // bmAttributes
EP_2_OUT_LEN, // wMaxPacketSize
1, // bInterval in ms.
},

};

static const ROMPTR uint8_t mouse_report_descriptor[] ={
0x5,0x0D,//Usage Page (Digitizer)
0x9,0x4,//Usage (Touch Screen)
0xA1,0x1,//Collection (Application)
0x85,0x73,//    Report ID (115)
0x9,0x54,//    Usage (Contact Count)
0x15,0x0,//    Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1F,//    Logical Maximum (31)
0x75,0x8,//    Report Size (8)
0x95,0x1,//    Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x22,//    Usage (Finger)
0xA1,0x2,//    Collection (Logical)
0x9,0x51,//        Usage (Contact Identifier)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0,//   Logical Maximum (255)
0x75,0x8,//        Report Size (8)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x42,//        Usage (Tip Switch)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x32,//        Usage (In Range)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x75,0x6,//        Report Size (6)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x3,//        Input (Cnst,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x1,//        Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0F,//        Logical Maximum (4095)
0x35,0x0,//        Physical Minimum (0)
0x46,0xFF,0x0F,//        Physical Maximum (4095)
0x75,0x10,//        Report Size (16)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x9,0x30,//        Usage (X)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x31,//        Usage (Y)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x0D,//        Usage Page (Digitizer)
0xC0,//    End Collection
0x9,0x22,//    Usage (Finger)
0xA1,0x2,//    Collection (Logical)
0x9,0x51,//        Usage (Contact Identifier)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0,//        Logical Maximum (255)
0x75,0x8,//        Report Size (8)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x42,//        Usage (Tip Switch)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x32,//        Usage (In Range)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x75,0x6,//        Report Size (6)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x3,//        Input (Cnst,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x1,//        Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0F,//        Logical Maximum (4095)
0x35,0x0,//        Physical Minimum (0)
0x46,0xFF,0x0F,//        Physical Maximum (4095)
0x75,0x10,//        Report Size (16)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x9,0x30,//        Usage (X)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x31,//        Usage (Y)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x0D,//        Usage Page (Digitizer)
0xC0,//    End Collection
0x9,0x22,//    Usage (Finger)
0xA1,0x2,//    Collection (Logical)
0x9,0x51,//        Usage (Contact Identifier)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0,//        Logical Maximum (255)
0x75,0x8,//        Report Size (8)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x42,//        Usage (Tip Switch)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x32,//        Usage (In Range)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75 ,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x75,0x6,//        Report Size (6)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1
0x81,0x3,//        Input (Cnst,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x1,//        Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0F,//        Logical Maximum (4095)
0x35,0x0,//        Physical Minimum (0)
0x46,0xFF,0x0F,//        Physical Maximum (4095)
0x75,0x10,//        Report Size (16)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x9,0x30,//        Usage (X)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x31,//        Usage (Y)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x0D,//        Usage Page (Digitizer)
0xC0,//    End 
0x9,0x22,//    Usage (Finger)
0xA1,0x2,//    Collection (Logical)
0x9,0x51,//        Usage (Contact Identifier)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0,//        Logical Maximum (255)
0x75,0x8,//        Report Size (8)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x42,//        Usage (Tip Switch)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x32,//        Usage (In Range)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x75,0x6,//        Report Size (6)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x3,//        Input (Cnst,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x1,//        Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0F,//        Logical Maximum (4095)
0x35,0x0,//        Physical Minimum (0)
0x46,0xFF,0x0F,//        Physical Maximum (4095)
0x75,0x10,//        Report Size (16)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x9,0x30,//        Usage (X)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x31,//        Usage (Y)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x0D,//        Usage Page (Digitizer)
0xC0,//    End Collection
0x9,0x22,//    Usage (Finger)
0xA1,0x2,//    Collection (Logical)
0x9,0x51,//        Usage (Contact Identifier)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0,//        Logical Maximum (255)
0x75,0x8,//        Report Size (8)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x42,//        Usage (Tip Switch)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x32,//        Usage (In Range)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x75,0x6,//        Report Size (6)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x3,//        Input (Cnst,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x1,//        Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0F,//        Logical Maximum (4095)
0x35,0x0,//        Physical Minimum (0)
0x46,0xFF,0x0F,//        Physical Maximum (4095)
0x75,0x10,//        Report Size (16)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x9,0x30,//        Usage (X)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x31,//        Usage (Y)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x0D,//        Usage Page (Digitizer)
0xC0,//    End Collection
0x5,0x0D,//    Usage Page (Digitizer)
0x15,0x0,//    Logical Minimum (0)
0x27,0xFF,0xFF,0x0,//    Logical Maximum (65535)
0x55,0x0C,//    Unit Exponent (-4)
0x66,0x1,0x10,//    Unit (SI Lin: Time (s))
0x75,0x10,//    Report Size (16)
0x95,0x1,//    Report Count (1)
0x9,0x56,//    Usage (Scan Time)
0x81,0x2,//    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x85,0x74,//    Report ID (116)
0x9,0x55,//    Usage (Contact Count Maximum)
0x15,0x0,//    Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1F,//    Logical Maximum (31)
0x75,0x8,//    Report Size (8)
0x95,0x1,//    Report Count (1)
0xB1,0x2,//    Feature (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,NVol,Bit)
0x85,0x75,//    Report ID (117)
0x6,0x0,0xFF,//    Usage Page (Vendor-Defined 1)
0x9,0xC5,//    Usage (Vendor-Defined 197)
0x15,0x0,//    Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0,//    Logical Maximum (255)
0x75,0x8,//    Report Size (8)
0x96,0x0,0x1,//    Report Count (256)
0xB1,0x2,//    Feature (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,NVol,Bit)
0xC0,//End Collection
0x5,0x0D,//Usage Page (Digitizer)
0x9,0x0,//Usage (Undefined)
0xA1,0x1,//Collection (Application)
0x85,0x77,//    Report ID (119)
0x9,0x20,//    Usage (Stylus)
0xA1,0x2,//    Collection (Logical)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x9,0x42,//        Usage (Tip Switch)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x32,//        Usage (In Range)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x44,//        Usage (Barrel Switch)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x45,//        Usage (Eraser)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x95,0x4,//        Report Count (4)
0x81,0x3,//        Input (Cnst,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x1,//        Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
0x55,0x0,//        Unit Exponent (0)
0x65,0x11,//        Unit (SI Lin: Length (cm))
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0F,//        Logical Maximum (4095)
0x35,0x0,//        Physical Minimum (0)
0x46,0xFF,0x0F,//        Physical Maximum (4095)
0x75,0x10,//        Report Size (16)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x9,0x30,//        Usage (X)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x31,//        Usage (Y)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x0D,//        Usage Page (Digitizer)
0x9,0x30,//        Usage (Tip Pressure)
0x15,0x1,//        Logical Minimum (1)
0x26,0xFF,0x0,//        Logical Maximum (255)
0x75,0x8,//        Report Size (8)
0x95,0x1,//        Report Count (1)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0xC0,//    End Collection
0xC0,//End Collection
0x5,0x0D,//Usage Page (Digitizer)
0x9,0x0E,//Usage (Configuration)
0xA1,0x1,//Collection (Application)
0x85,0x71,//    Report ID (113)
0x9,0x23,//    Usage (Device Settings)
0xA1,0x2,//    Collection (Logical)
0x9,0x52,//        Usage (Device Mode)
0x9,0x53,//        Usage (Device Identifier)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x0A,//        Logical Maximum (10)
0x75,0x8,//        Report Size (8)
0x95,0x2,//        Report Count (2)
0xB1,0x2,//        Feature (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,NVol,Bit)
0xC0,//    End Collection
0xC0//End Collection

};
static const ROMPTR uint8_t mouse_report_descriptor_1[]={
0x6,0x0,0xFF,//Usage Page (Vendor-Defined 1)
0x9,0x1,//Usage (Vendor-Defined 1)
0xA1,0x1,//Collection (Application)
0x85,0x76,//    Report ID (118)
0x15,0x0,//    Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0,//    Logical Maximum (255)
0x75,0x8,//    Report Size (8)
0x95,0x3F,//    Report Count (63)
0x9,0x1,//    Usage (Vendor-Defined 1)
0x81,0x2,//    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x9,0x1,//    Usage (Vendor-Defined 1)
0x91,0x2,//    Output (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,NVol,Bit)
0xc0
};
static const ROMPTR uint8_t mouse_report_descriptor_2[]={
0x5,0x01,//Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
0x9,0x02,//Usage (Mouse)
0xA1,0x1,//Collection (Application)
0x85,0x72,//    Report ID (114)
0x9,0x1,//    Usage (Pointer)
0xA1,0x0,//    Collection (Physical)
0x5,0x9,//        Usage Page (Button)
0x19,0x1,//        Usage Minimum (Button 1)
0x29,0x2,//        Usage Maximum (Button 2)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x25,0x1,//        Logical Maximum (1)
0x75,0x1,//        Report Size (1)
0x95,0x2,//        Report Count (2)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x95,0x6,//        Report Count (6)
0x81,0x3,//        Input (Cnst,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0x5,0x1,//        Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
0x9,0x30,//        Usage (X)
0x9,0x31,//        Usage (Y)
0x15,0x0,//        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26,0xFF,0x0F,//        Logical Maximum (4095)
0x35,0x0,//        Physical Minimum (0)
0x46,0xFF,0x0F,//        Physical Maximum (4095)
0x75,0x10,//        Report Size (16)
0x95,0x2,//        Report Count (2)
0x81,0x2,//        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit)
0xC0,//    End Collection
0xC0,//End Collection

};
```

Here is what usblyzer shows
        HID Descriptor
    Usage Page: 65280 (Vendor Specific)
    Usage: 1 (Unknown)
    Collection 
    Report ID: 118
    Logical Minimum: 0
    Logical Maximum: 255
    Report Size: 8
    Report Count: 63
    Usage: 1 (Unknown)
    Input: 2 (Data,Variable,Absolute,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)

```
Usage: 1 (Unknown)
Output: 2 (Data,Variable,Absolute,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non Volatile)

End Collection 
Reserved Item 
Report Size: 0
Reserved Item 
Unit: 0
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Unit: 0
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 

Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
HID Descriptor
Usage Page: 13 (Digitizer)
Usage: 4 (Touch Screen)
Collection 
Report ID: 115
Usage: 84 (Contact Count)
Logical Minimum: 0
Logical Maximum: 31
Report Size: 8
Report Count: 1
Input: 2 (Data,Variable,Absolute,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)

Usage: 34 (Finger)
Collection 
Usage: 81 (Contact ID)
Logical Minimum: 32
HID Descriptor
Usage Page: 65280 (Vendor Specific)
Usage: 1 (Unknown)
Collection 
Report ID: 118
Logical Minimum: 0
Logical Maximum: 255
Report Size: 8
Report Count: 63
Usage: 1 (Unknown)
Input: 2 (Data,Variable,Absolute,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)

Usage: 1 (Unknown)
Output: 2 (Data,Variable,Absolute,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non Volatile)

End Collection 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item 
Reserved Item
```